# Style of LWUIT ComboBox

Tags: java-me, combobox, styles, lwuit

I'm working in a project and use LWUIT, I want to make a custom style for Combobox and Successfully after a lot of search I have made it by changing the cell renderer and the look and feel to change arrow icon

the problem now that the white space around my items I want to remove them, how can I do that please

[image: Combobox Style]

Answer (score 0):

You should start setting the padding/margin entries for various styles to 0, we changed the styles here a bit at [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) so i don't quite recall everything but try PopupList, PopupItem, ComboBoxPopupList,  etc.